# Hardware Spec for vmWare with 2 VM

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, storage

I have the opportunity to build a new server for an organization. I plan to up VmWare ESXi 6.5 free on it. I will run 2 VM.

The first VM will be a Windows DC to handle 6 laptops and file storage.
The second VM will run Centos7 and run Seafile Community.

Planning on high end RAM and Xeon, but for storage and for host OS installation, what should I do? A mirrored SD array for ESXi? One huge data store for two file server and let the hardware handle the RAID? Or two separate arrays for each VM? Or one RAID array for the windows box and JBOD for the second Linux VM and let the VM handle the software RAID?

Comment: You don't need high-end RAM as such, just regular ECC memory will be fine. Hardware R1/10 with SSDs will be fine, so will one big datastore, make sure your format it with VMFS 6.

Comment: So use a hardware RAID controller to make a RAID6 to present to ESXi?

Comment: Sure, seems fine to me.